# How to build Angular and upload it to the server?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I installed Angular Universal in my Angular project. When I build after installing, 2 files named browser and server are created. I don't know how to upload these files to the server. Previously, there was only a file called assets in the dist folder. What should I do now?

Comment: What backend stack are you using?

Comment: i'm using Natro Server

Comment: Yes, but are you hosting your angular app through a backend, for example ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

The naming is quite explicit :

- `browser` : is the client side rendering (CSR) version
- `server` : is the servie side rendering (SSR) version.

You will need to upload the `server` dist.

Comment: There are only js files in the server file. I don't know how to use server side. I will inform our team leader about this and he will use the server side. As far as I understand, we will upload the server file to the server side and the browser file to the browser side?

Comment: If you use SSR, you won't need to use the CSR files

Comment: How to transfer the server file to the server side or run it there?